# Is there any event for time field of owl-date-time in angular2 date picker?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is there any event  for time field of owl-date-time in angular2 date picker

I have implemented date time picker in my project , in it's time field we r able to enter any alphabet or special character , it doesn't get reflected in final value but i want that when user tries to enter a alphabet then it should show an alert like alphabets are not allowed.

Comment: your question doesn't explain anything, please ask a more specific question or point out to an exact problem.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this web-site for Angular Date Time Picker event.

```
       https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime
```